# How to use an existing SQL DB with a new C1 installation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, c1-cms

I want to install a new Composite C1 installation to save me the trouble of manual upgrade process over multiple version. I can easily recreate the state of the old installation anyway.

I want however reuse the data I already have in my old Composite SQL database.

My problem is, that if I make a clean install and then install the SQL package, C1 will try to create a new database instead of using the existing one.

What's the easiest way to reuse my existing database?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familar with the software you are referring to, but you might check to see if the newer version changed anything in the database (table columns, views, etc). You could let it install the new database and then do a compare between the new one and existing, to find any differences. If you find no differences then just take a backup of the existing database and restore it to the new one.

You will probably want to check the software's documentation on restoring the database incase there is any special measures to take prior to and after doing it.

Comment: The problem does not lie in restoring the database, but to get Composite C1 to use the existing one. I was unable to find any documentation on how to do this, that's why I am asking. ;)

Comment: http://docs.composite.net/Packages/CompositeC1Tools/SQLServerDataProvider reading this it looks like you could change the connection string to point to the old database.